Django `db_table` not renaming table
This question is (surprisingly) unlike similar ones, which ask about doing this dynamically, or ask how to do it in the first place. This question regards those suggestions not working as expected.
Brief summary of situation:

We made a series of Django apps as part of an API used in a real web app.
We named those apps in ways that made sense at the time, e.g., "organizations" and "authentication".
Now, we are packaging these apps as a distributable library, so a third party can install our apps in their API.
The client already has apps named "organizations" and "authentication", causing conflicts (because Django apps must have unique names).
Because we are creating the reusable library, we are renaming our apps from organizations to mycompany_organizations to make them unique and distinguishable.
I have made a series of migrations following this guide to create a new app and move the models over without losing data.
Everything worked until someone added a new app that referenced our Organization model. This migration results in relation my_company_organization does not exist, despite multiple foreign keys already pointing to my_company_organizations.organization and working fine.
I inspected the database and found that the table names were still in the style of organizations_organization instead of my_company_organizations_organization.
I set db_table = "my_company_organization" on the MyCompanyOrganization model to try to rename the database table.
I made and ran migrations. I verified that the 000x_alter_organization_table migration has been successfully applied.
I still get the same error on the first migration in the new app.
I inspected the database, and the table name is still organizations_organization!

How can I rename the database table using Django migrations? Changing db_table is plainly not working.
Here is the code of a migration that renames a table:
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ("my_company_organizations", "0005_do_stuff"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelTable(
            name="organization",
            table="my_company_organizations_organization",
        ),
        migrations.AlterModelTable(
            name="organizationemaildomain",
            table="my_company_organizations_organizationemaildomain",
        ),
    ]

Neither of these tables are actually renamed to my_company_x after successfully running the migration.
Update: It works if the new app depends not only on the latest migration in the my_company_organizations app, but also the latest migration in the old organizations app (which is depended upon by the new app). It makes no sense to me, since the migrations to rename the tables, and all migrations in the old app, have been executed before it reaches the failing migration anyway. Adding the dependency should change nothing because the migrations it depends on have already been executed anyway, but adding that dependency works for some reason, and I see the rename in the database. I can't help but consider this a bug in Django.

Not really an answer, but have you considered running separate SQL and state migrations in old app instead of creating new app? Move your alter table to 'state_operations'   and rename your tables using SQL in 'db_operations'. This way Django will know that table names have changed, but won't be responsible for changing that.

I did do that, but in conjunction with creating a new app. The goal is to rename the app, not just the tables, because the app names themselves must be unique. I don't see how I could rename the app without creating a new one. Maybe by squashing migrations and saying the squashed migration in the "new" app name replaces all migrations in the old?
